# How to create routes path into resource in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand resource and path routes in rails 3 but I do not know is there any way to have both routes ? I try this routes but it not work for me, this is the routes:

```
resources :roles, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update]
 get '/roles/:id' => 'roles#available_users'
```

How can we routes to use both routes ?

thankyou very much

Comment: what is the use case? why you need same route for different actions?

Comment: It's not possible to have same route for different actions. Just think, how interpreter will get to know that where the request should go. As @Mandeep said, explain your use case, may be we can achieve that with some alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes**

What you're asking for cannot be done, as you'll be using the same "route" for different controller actions:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :roles, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update] #-> domain.com/roles/:id - roles#show
```

If you then create another route for `domain.com/roles/:id`, Rails will just take the first which it finds in the `routes` file

--

The way to fix your issue is likely to be down to the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :roles, except: [:edit, :destroy] do
   get :available_users # -> domain.com/roles/:id/available_users
end
```

This will take you to the `roles#available_users` action, providing you with the ability to load the view you wish (to display the users for a particular role)

For a more defined explanation, I'd recommend checking out the [`nested_resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) part of the Rails routing system

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
resources :roles, only: [:index, :create, :update] do
  get '/roles/:id' => 'roles#available_users'
end
```

Correct?
Just add an "do" behind the closing ] and an end after the custom routes.

Edit: Apparently I got wrong. ;) What you could do is:

```
resources :roles, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update] do
  get '/roles/:id/available' => 'roles#available_users'
end
```